# Why does adding a View after initialization throws NLP but not during initialization, using afterburner.fx

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am using afterburner.fx http://afterburner.adam-bien.com/

It works as advertised. I can add multiple fxml Files to a central/main "view".

But if I want to add another fxml/presenter later, for example, using a button on a different navigationPane to add another fxml to the mainAnchorPane.
Then it throws a NullPointerException.

```
public class MainscenePresenter implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    AnchorPane breadcrumbAnchor;

    @FXML
    AnchorPane navigationAnchor;

    //--------------------------------------------------------
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane mainAnchorPane; //ADD NEW ATPANE HERE

    private AtPresenter atPresenter;
    private AtView atView;

    //--------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        //add BreadCrumBar WORKS
        BreadcrumbbarView breadcrumbbarView = new BreadcrumbbarView();
        breadcrumbbarView.getViewAsync(breadcrumbAnchor.getChildren()::add);

        //add DFD  WORKS
        DfdView dfdView = new DfdView();
        Parent view2 = dfdView.getView();
        this.mainAnchorPane.getChildren().add(view2);

        //add Navigation  WORKS
        NavigationView navigationView = new NavigationView();
        Parent view = navigationView.getView();
        navigationAnchor.getChildren().add(view);

        //add AT
        this.atView = new AtView();
        this.atPresenter = (AtPresenter) this.atView.getPresenter();

        //ADDING AT VIEW LIKE THIS WORKS <=========================
        this.showAt();

    }

    void showAt() {
        this.mainAnchorPane.getChildren().add(this.atView.getView()); // <== NLP here if invoked with buttonAt
    }

    public void buttonAt() {
        //ADDING AT VIEW LIKE THIS(Button on different Presenter) DOES NOT WORK => NLP
        this.showAt();
    }
}



public class NavigationPresenter implements Initializable {

@FXML
Button atNavButton;

@Inject
MainscenePresenter mainscene;

private ResourceBundle resources = null;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    this.resources = resources;
}

@FXML
void showDfdScene(ActionEvent event) {
    mainscene.buttonAt();
}
}
```

[image]

It seems I don't understand some central mechanism of JavaFX! And can't name it, to look it up!

Why does it throw NullPointerException in this case and not durin initialization?

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at abc.abc.app.mainscene.MainscenePresenter.showAt(MainscenePresenter.java:107)
at abc.abc.app.mainscene.MainscenePresenter.buttonAt(MainscenePresenter.java:112)
at abc.abc.app.navigation.NavigationPresenter.showDfdScene(NavigationPresenter.java:41)
... 58 more
```

Comment: What is null? And how is `buttonAt()` being invoked?

Comment: Are you sure the controller instance you call the `buttonAt` method for is the same one that is used when loading the fxml?

Comment: @fabian no to Button is on a different controller, then invokes this buttonAt()

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza Please do not put stack traces in blockquotes, since this drastically reduces readability since line breaks are not preserved.

Comment: @James_D NLP in void showAt() {
        this.mainAnchorPane.getChildren().add(this.atView.getView()); // <== NLP here if invoked with buttonAt
    } if invoked with buttonAt from a different controller

Comment: @Wozilla The method is in a different controller (`NavigationPresenter`), but it does invoke a method in `MainscenePresenter` (the line should look something like this `mainscenePresenter.buttonAt()`). I guess the `MainscenePresenter` instance (`mainscenePresenter`) is not the one used when the fxml is loaded. Could you add a code snippet that highlights where the `MainscenePresenter` instance comes from and how the fxml is loaded?

Comment: @fabian understood. Thanks.

Comment: I saw that already: I was asking what is actually null? I.e. is it `mainAnchorPane` or is it `atView`? More generally, though, if one presenter is calling a method in another presenter, you are already on the wrong track: you're introducing coupling between presenters that really shouldn't be there. You should have each presenter interact with (call methods on, and observe properties in) a model. You can inject a shared model instance into each presenter (which is the whole point of afterburner.fx).

Comment: @James_D the mainAnchorPane is Null. A simple this.mainAnchorPane.getChildren().clear(); also thorws NLP. And yes there are better ways to do it. I think I have seen your sugestion in different answers and it is better and i will try that. But on my way I am trying this to learn and understand it.

Comment: If you `@Inject` one presenter into another, afterburner will treat the injected presenter as a "service"; i.e. it will create and cache an instance for use for injection. That isn't the same instance as (any of) the instances actually created when you load an FXML file (for one thing, you get a new presenter instance each time you load the FXML file , so if you loaded `mainscene.fxml` more than once, which instance would be injected? what if you hadn't loaded it at all?). Since it's not an instance created by loading FXML, `@FXML`-annotated fields are not initialized. Hence the NPE.

Comment: @James_D ah interesting yes. I have read simmilar explanation of yours on a different question. Makes sens. Then I want to ask you if you can point me to an example, regarding your first suggestion of using an "injected shared model instance for each presenter"?

Comment: Just write a class `public class MyModelClass { ... }` and do `@Inject private MyModelClass myModel ;` in each presenter. It will inject the same instance to both, so you can use the model to share data between the presenters.

Comment: Summarized comments in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afterburner.fx is a dependency-injection framework for JavaFX. The main functionality it provides is the ability to inject objects into the controllers/presenters that are created when you load an FXML file (by instantiating a subclass of `FXMLView`). The basic process that happens when you instantiate a `FXMLView` is:

1. A new instance of the corresponding presenter is created
2. The presenter is inspected to find any `@Inject`-annotated fields
3. For each `@Inject`-annotated field, if an instance of that type exists in the injector's cache, it is set as the value of that field. Otherwise, a new instance of that type is created and placed in the cache, and set as the value of the field.

The main point to note here is that the presenters themselves are treated differently to their dependencies. If you try (as in your code) to inject one presenter in another, an instance of the presenter class will be created specifically for injection purposes: this will not be the same instance that is created when the FXML file is loaded, and consequently it won't have any `@FXML`-fields injected. This is why you get a null pointer exception: `mainAnchorPane` is null in the ``MainScenePresenter`that is injected into the`NavigationPresenter`.

One presenter having a reference to another is generally a bad idea anyway: it creates unnecessary coupling between the two presenters. Instead, you should inject a model into both presenters that represents the state you want to share between them. In your case you might have something like

```
public class ViewState {

    private final BooleanProperty atShowing = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    public BooleanProperty atShowingProperty() {
        return atShowing ;
    }

    public final boolean isAtShowing() {
        return atShowingProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setAtShowing(boolean atShowing) {
        atShowingProperty().set(atShowing);
    }
}
```

Now in your presenters, do

```
public class MainscenePresenter implements Initializable {

    @Inject
    private ViewState viewState ;

    @FXML
    AnchorPane breadcrumbAnchor;

    @FXML
    AnchorPane navigationAnchor;

    //------------------------------------------------------
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane mainAnchorPane; //ADD NEW ATPANE HERE

    private AtPresenter atPresenter;
    private AtView atView;

    //------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        //add BreadCrumBar WORKS
        BreadcrumbbarView breadcrumbbarView = new BreadcrumbbarView();
        breadcrumbbarView.getViewAsync(breadcrumbAnchor.getChildren()::add);

        //add DFD  WORKS
        DfdView dfdView = new DfdView();
        Parent view2 = dfdView.getView();
        this.mainAnchorPane.getChildren().add(view2);

        //add Navigation  WORKS
        NavigationView navigationView = new NavigationView();
        Parent view = navigationView.getView();
        navigationAnchor.getChildren().add(view);

        //add AT
        this.atView = new AtView();
        this.atPresenter = (AtPresenter) this.atView.getPresenter();

        this.viewState.atShowingProperty().addListener((obs, wasShowing, isNowShowing) -> {
            if (isNowShowing) {
                this.mainAnchorPane.getChildren().remove(this.atView.getView());
            } else {
                this.mainAnchorPane.getChildren().add(this.atView.getView());
            }
        });
    }      
}
```

and

```
public class NavigationPresenter implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    Button atNavButton;

    @Inject
    private ViewState viewState ;

    private ResourceBundle resources = null;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        this.resources = resources;
    }

    @FXML
    void showDfdScene(ActionEvent event) {
        viewState.setAtShowing(true);
    }  
}
```

Comment: I tried it: It wörks! This is correct! You are correct!